# How to extract lines starting with the same first 2 characters, then output to separate files?

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, scripting

I have a very large text list and need a way to extract lines beginning with the same 2 characters, then save those lines to separate files named after those 2 characters.

Example List:

```
abWEye7kgw7  
abff34ZSrZf  
abke8mzMyma  
b2R5mPZGbCb  
b2zhhCeLZzZ  
b2q2T5rkACp  
k9ekzbc8nUh  
k9QzXBUrNT7  
k92RtdXntZ3  
vrTtR9GmbWG  
vraVM9QXWzY  
vrME9QnksBf
```

Desired Output:

```
ab* > ab.txt  
b2* > b2.txt  
k9* > k9.txt  
vr* > vr.txt
```

The list is rather large and there are lots of first 2 character combinations.

Comment: will the list always be sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ f = substr($0,1,2) ".txt"; print >f }' file.in

$ ls
ab.txt  b2.txt  file.in k9.txt  vr.txt

$ cat ab.txt
abWEye7kgw7
abff34ZSrZf
abke8mzMyma
```

This can obviously be solved in the shell too, but `awk` is better suited for parsing text files.  The `substr()` picks out the first two characters of each line in the input file, and this is assigned to the variable `f` with `.txt` added to the end.  The `print` will output the current line to the file whose name is in `f`.

I believe you can do away with the `f` variable and use the `substr()` expression directly after `>`, but not in the `awk` implementation that I'm using on OpenBSD (this is possibly a bug).

---

If the number of different combinations of two first characters are too many, you may have issues with too many open files.

The following variation will take care of that:

```
awk '{ f = substr($0,1,2) ".txt"; print >>f; close(f) }' file.in
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, if the number of different two-character combinations are too many. I will add an alternative solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution:

```
awk -v FS='' '{ print > $1$2".txt" }' file
```

---

One of the resulting files:

```
$ cat k9.txt 
k9ekzbc8nUh
k9QzXBUrNT7
k92RtdXntZ3
```

Comment: Since you're not explicitly closing the output files after each `print`, they will not be truncated if the input file isn't sorted, so it'll will work on unsorted data too. (if it wouldn't work, it wouldn't work on sorted data either)

Comment: @Kusalananda, let's say: It should work (in our case)

Comment: It should be noted that the behaviour for an empty FS is unspecified per POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`cat list.txt | while IFS= read -r st; do echo $st >> ${st:0:2}.txt; done`

Comment: Why the `cat`? Use `while ...; do ...; done <list.txt` instead.

Comment: The old bad habit. Yes, you're right, it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below method to achieve the result. Tested its works fine

```
 for j in `awk '{print substr($1,1,2)}' k.txt  | uniq -c | awk '$1 >=2 {print $2}'`; do sed -n "/^$j/p" k.txt > $j.txt; done
```

It extracts the first two character of each line. If First 2 character is same in more than 1 line.  it will prints the related line save the lines in filename of first 2 charater

Output

```
 cat ab.txt
    abWEye7kgw7
    abff34ZSrZf
    abke8mzMyma

    cat b2.txt
    b2R5mPZGbCb
    b2zhhCeLZzZ
    b2q2T5rkACp

     cat k9.txt
    k9ekzbc8nUh
    k9QzXBUrNT7
    k92RtdXntZ3

 cat vr.txt
vrTtR9GmbWG
vraVM9QXWzY
vrME9QnksBf
```